# How to write javascript for a list of unique colorful text with background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I need to generate a list (as many as I can) of colored label. They should be different color combined with its own whatever background color as long as the text is clear. (no background is ok, but the text should be clear on white and grey background canvas)

I have been hard-coding them. But it's not a good idea. There are solutions for generating random color by using jQuery color plugin. But what I need can't be random so to avoid any possible duplication or even closeness.

My current idea is hard coding "enough" so it won't run out of "budget". The business case is to represent similar data from different category in a calendar, the color will indicate the different category.

I would appreciate a real solution to solve this problem.

My current hard-coded function

```
calendar.color = function (site) {
    switch(site) {

        case "abcae": return {color: 'yellow', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abcca": return {color: 'rosybrown', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abcbr": return {color: 'lightpink', textColor: 'black'};
        case 'abccn': return {color: 'crimson', textColor: 'yellow'};
        case "abccom": return {color: 'deeppink', textColor: 'yellow'};
        case "abcde": return {color: 'darkmagenta', textColor: 'yellow'};
        case "abceu": return {color: 'indigo', textColor: 'yellow'};
        case "abcfr": return {color: 'darkslateblue', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abchk": return {color: 'blue', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abchu": return {color: 'lightsteelblue', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abcin": return {color: 'skyblue', textColor: 'darkmagenta'};
        case "abcit": return {color: 'darkturquoise', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abcro": return {color: 'aqua', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abcru": return {color: 'darkcyan', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abcnl": return {color: 'seagreen', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abcmx": return {color: 'lightgreen', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abces": return {color: 'lime', textColor: 'black'};
        case "abcpl": return {color: 'gray', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abcuk": return {color: 'olive', textColor: 'white'};
        case "abcus": return {color: 'orange', textColor: 'darkblue'};

        default: return {color: 'cadetblue', textColor: 'white'};
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the code you have to provide a starting point.

Comment: Yes, Just did. It's hard code. Not scalable at all. Only works for now.

Comment: How many labels do you need?

Comment: Less than 200 I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

using this js plugin (https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor), you can generate a background color, then use this contrast plugin from https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/ to choose an appropriate text color.

```
// https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/
function getContrast(hexcolor){
    hexcolor = hexcolor.replace('#', '');
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(0,2),16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(2,2),16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4,2),16);
    var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
    return (yiq >= 128) ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
}

function genColors(num) {
    var color, bg, text, colorset, colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        color = randomColor();
        text = getContrast(color);
        bg = color;
        colorset = text+','+bg;
        colors.push(colorset);
    }
    return colors;
}
```

then iterate through the array like so;

```
var colors = genColors(256);

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var set = colors[i].split(',');
    var text = set[0];
    var bg = set[1];
    console.log(set);
}
```

its a bit of a mashup, but hopefully it does what you need.

alternatively, I made a pastebin for you http://pastebin.com/aLRHMwTG

here is a little test to show you that it works

```js
// randomColor by David Merfield under the CC0 license
// https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor/

;
(function(root, factory) {

  // Support AMD
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory);

    // Support CommonJS
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    var randomColor = factory();

    // Support NodeJS & Component, which allow module.exports to be a function
    if (typeof module === 'object' && module && module.exports) {
      exports = module.exports = randomColor;
    }

    // Support CommonJS 1.1.1 spec
    exports.randomColor = randomColor;

    // Support vanilla script loading
  } else {
    root.randomColor = factory();
  }

}(this, function() {

  // Seed to get repeatable colors
  var seed = null;

  // Shared color dictionary
  var colorDictionary = {};

  // Populate the color dictionary
  loadColorBounds();

  var randomColor = function(options) {

    options = options || {};

    // Check if there is a seed and ensure it's an
    // integer. Otherwise, reset the seed value.
    if (options.seed !== undefined && options.seed !== null && options.seed === parseInt(options.seed, 10)) {
      seed = options.seed;

      // A string was passed as a seed
    } else if (typeof options.seed === 'string') {
      seed = stringToInteger(options.seed);

      // Something was passed as a seed but it wasn't an integer or string
    } else if (options.seed !== undefined && options.seed !== null) {
      throw new TypeError('The seed value must be an integer or string');

      // No seed, reset the value outside.
    } else {
      seed = null;
    }

    var H, S, B;

    // Check if we need to generate multiple colors
    if (options.count !== null && options.count !== undefined) {

      var totalColors = options.count,
        colors = [];

      options.count = null;

      while (totalColors > colors.length) {

        // Since we're generating multiple colors,
        // incremement the seed. Otherwise we'd just
        // generate the same color each time...
        if (seed && options.seed) options.seed += 1;

        colors.push(randomColor(options));
      }

      options.count = totalColors;

      return colors;
    }

    // First we pick a hue (H)
    H = pickHue(options);

    // Then use H to determine saturation (S)
    S = pickSaturation(H, options);

    // Then use S and H to determine brightness (B).
    B = pickBrightness(H, S, options);

    // Then we return the HSB color in the desired format
    return setFormat([H, S, B], options);
  };

  function pickHue(options) {

    var hueRange = getHueRange(options.hue),
      hue = randomWithin(hueRange);

    // Instead of storing red as two seperate ranges,
    // we group them, using negative numbers
    if (hue < 0) {
      hue = 360 + hue;
    }

    return hue;

  }

  function pickSaturation(hue, options) {

    if (options.luminosity === 'random') {
      return randomWithin([0, 100]);
    }

    if (options.hue === 'monochrome') {
      return 0;
    }

    var saturationRange = getSaturationRange(hue);

    var sMin = saturationRange[0],
      sMax = saturationRange[1];

    switch (options.luminosity) {

      case 'bright':
        sMin = 55;
        break;

      case 'dark':
        sMin = sMax - 10;
        break;

      case 'light':
        sMax = 55;
        break;
    }

    return randomWithin([sMin, sMax]);

  }

  function pickBrightness(H, S, options) {

    var bMin = getMinimumBrightness(H, S),
      bMax = 100;

    switch (options.luminosity) {

      case 'dark':
        bMax = bMin + 20;
        break;

      case 'light':
        bMin = (bMax + bMin) / 2;
        break;

      case 'random':
        bMin = 0;
        bMax = 100;
        break;
    }

    return randomWithin([bMin, bMax]);
  }

  function setFormat(hsv, options) {

    switch (options.format) {

      case 'hsvArray':
        return hsv;

      case 'hslArray':
        return HSVtoHSL(hsv);

      case 'hsl':
        var hsl = HSVtoHSL(hsv);
        return 'hsl(' + hsl[0] + ', ' + hsl[1] + '%, ' + hsl[2] + '%)';

      case 'hsla':
        var hslColor = HSVtoHSL(hsv);
        var alpha = options.alpha || Math.random();
        return 'hsla(' + hslColor[0] + ', ' + hslColor[1] + '%, ' + hslColor[2] + '%, ' + alpha + ')';

      case 'rgbArray':
        return HSVtoRGB(hsv);

      case 'rgb':
        var rgb = HSVtoRGB(hsv);
        return 'rgb(' + rgb.join(', ') + ')';

      case 'rgba':
        var rgbColor = HSVtoRGB(hsv);
        var alpha = options.alpha || Math.random();
        return 'rgba(' + rgbColor.join(', ') + ', ' + alpha + ')';

      default:
        return HSVtoHex(hsv);
    }

  }

  function getMinimumBrightness(H, S) {

    var lowerBounds = getColorInfo(H).lowerBounds;

    for (var i = 0; i < lowerBounds.length - 1; i++) {

      var s1 = lowerBounds[i][0],
        v1 = lowerBounds[i][1];

      var s2 = lowerBounds[i + 1][0],
        v2 = lowerBounds[i + 1][1];

      if (S >= s1 && S <= s2) {

        var m = (v2 - v1) / (s2 - s1),
          b = v1 - m * s1;

        return m * S + b;
      }

    }

    return 0;
  }

  function getHueRange(colorInput) {

    if (typeof parseInt(colorInput) === 'number') {

      var number = parseInt(colorInput);

      if (number < 360 && number > 0) {
        return [number, number];
      }

    }

    if (typeof colorInput === 'string') {

      if (colorDictionary[colorInput]) {
        var color = colorDictionary[colorInput];
        if (color.hueRange) {
          return color.hueRange;
        }
      }
    }

    return [0, 360];

  }

  function getSaturationRange(hue) {
    return getColorInfo(hue).saturationRange;
  }

  function getColorInfo(hue) {

    // Maps red colors to make picking hue easier
    if (hue >= 334 && hue <= 360) {
      hue -= 360;
    }

    for (var colorName in colorDictionary) {
      var color = colorDictionary[colorName];
      if (color.hueRange &&
        hue >= color.hueRange[0] &&
        hue <= color.hueRange[1]) {
        return colorDictionary[colorName];
      }
    }
    return 'Color not found';
  }

  function randomWithin(range) {
    if (seed === null) {
      return Math.floor(range[0] + Math.random() * (range[1] + 1 - range[0]));
    } else {
      //Seeded random algorithm from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
      var max = range[1] || 1;
      var min = range[0] || 0;
      seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
      var rnd = seed / 233280.0;
      return Math.floor(min + rnd * (max - min));
    }
  }

  function HSVtoHex(hsv) {

    var rgb = HSVtoRGB(hsv);

    function componentToHex(c) {
      var hex = c.toString(16);
      return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
    }

    var hex = '#' + componentToHex(rgb[0]) + componentToHex(rgb[1]) + componentToHex(rgb[2]);

    return hex;

  }

  function defineColor(name, hueRange, lowerBounds) {

    var sMin = lowerBounds[0][0],
      sMax = lowerBounds[lowerBounds.length - 1][0],

      bMin = lowerBounds[lowerBounds.length - 1][1],
      bMax = lowerBounds[0][1];

    colorDictionary[name] = {
      hueRange: hueRange,
      lowerBounds: lowerBounds,
      saturationRange: [sMin, sMax],
      brightnessRange: [bMin, bMax]
    };

  }

  function loadColorBounds() {

    defineColor(
      'monochrome',
      null, [
        [0, 0],
        [100, 0]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'red', [-26, 18], [
        [20, 100],
        [30, 92],
        [40, 89],
        [50, 85],
        [60, 78],
        [70, 70],
        [80, 60],
        [90, 55],
        [100, 50]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'orange', [19, 46], [
        [20, 100],
        [30, 93],
        [40, 88],
        [50, 86],
        [60, 85],
        [70, 70],
        [100, 70]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'yellow', [47, 62], [
        [25, 100],
        [40, 94],
        [50, 89],
        [60, 86],
        [70, 84],
        [80, 82],
        [90, 80],
        [100, 75]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'green', [63, 178], [
        [30, 100],
        [40, 90],
        [50, 85],
        [60, 81],
        [70, 74],
        [80, 64],
        [90, 50],
        [100, 40]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'blue', [179, 257], [
        [20, 100],
        [30, 86],
        [40, 80],
        [50, 74],
        [60, 60],
        [70, 52],
        [80, 44],
        [90, 39],
        [100, 35]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'purple', [258, 282], [
        [20, 100],
        [30, 87],
        [40, 79],
        [50, 70],
        [60, 65],
        [70, 59],
        [80, 52],
        [90, 45],
        [100, 42]
      ]
    );

    defineColor(
      'pink', [283, 334], [
        [20, 100],
        [30, 90],
        [40, 86],
        [60, 84],
        [80, 80],
        [90, 75],
        [100, 73]
      ]
    );

  }

  function HSVtoRGB(hsv) {

    // this doesn't work for the values of 0 and 360
    // here's the hacky fix
    var h = hsv[0];
    if (h === 0) {
      h = 1;
    }
    if (h === 360) {
      h = 359;
    }

    // Rebase the h,s,v values
    h = h / 360;
    var s = hsv[1] / 100,
      v = hsv[2] / 100;

    var h_i = Math.floor(h * 6),
      f = h * 6 - h_i,
      p = v * (1 - s),
      q = v * (1 - f * s),
      t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
      r = 256,
      g = 256,
      b = 256;

    switch (h_i) {
      case 0:
        r = v;
        g = t;
        b = p;
        break;
      case 1:
        r = q;
        g = v;
        b = p;
        break;
      case 2:
        r = p;
        g = v;
        b = t;
        break;
      case 3:
        r = p;
        g = q;
        b = v;
        break;
      case 4:
        r = t;
        g = p;
        b = v;
        break;
      case 5:
        r = v;
        g = p;
        b = q;
        break;
    }

    var result = [Math.floor(r * 255), Math.floor(g * 255), Math.floor(b * 255)];
    return result;
  }

  function HSVtoHSL(hsv) {
    var h = hsv[0],
      s = hsv[1] / 100,
      v = hsv[2] / 100,
      k = (2 - s) * v;

    return [
      h,
      Math.round(s * v / (k < 1 ? k : 2 - k) * 10000) / 100,
      k / 2 * 100
    ];
  }

  function stringToInteger(string) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i !== string.length; i++) {
      if (total >= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) break;
      total += string.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    return total
  }

  return randomColor;
}));


// https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/
function getContrast(hexcolor) {
  hexcolor = hexcolor.replace('#', '');
  var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(0, 2), 16);
  var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(2, 2), 16);
  var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4, 2), 16);
  var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
  return (yiq >= 128) ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
}

function genColors(num) {
  var color, bg, text, colorset, colors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    color = randomColor();
    text = getContrast(color);
    bg = color;
    colorset = text + ',' + bg;
    colors.push(colorset);
  }
  return colors;
}

var colors = genColors(256);

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  var set = colors[i].split(',');
  var text = set [0];
  var bg = set [1];
  var holdyDiv = $('<div style=" color:' + text + '; background-color:' + bg + '; display:inline-block; padding:25px;">test</div>').attr('id', 'holdy');
  holdyDiv.appendTo('body');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```